# How to select vertical data in MySQL table

Tags: mysql

If I have a table like this:

```
ID color size weight
1  red   2    3
2  green 4    5
```

So to run a mysql query to find the ID number that is color:red and size:2 and weight:3 I can do this:

```
select ID from table where color=red AND size=2 AND weight=3
```

As properties are growing in addition to color, weight, size, mileage, speed, etc... and I want to keep the table scaling it would make sense to organize it this way

```
ID  ID2  property  value
1   1    color     red
2   1    size      2
3   1    weight    3
4   2    color     green
5   2    size      4
6   2    weight    5
```

How do I run a select query here to find the ID number that is color:red and size:2 and weight:3

Comment: It depends on just how normalized you want your data, but you could break your properties into another table with `ID`,`Property`,`Value` and then reference that `ID` back in the main table (or normalize further with Properties having their own IDs and Values their own).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For key value structure one approach is to self join as many times as the no. of properties you have like in your case 3 properties (color,weight,size) so you need 2 self joins and for each,filter results according to properties like in below query i have given unique aliases so for the alias `t` i have filtered rows with `t.property = 'color'` and for value `t.value = 'red'` and same as for other aliases to find the desired `ids` which fits for the provided criteria,So if your criteria increases with another property you need another self join and same filtering as above

```
select t.id2 
from test t
join test t1 on(t.id = t1.ID2)
join test t2 on(t.id = t2.ID2)
where t.property = 'color'
and t1.property = 'size'
and t2.property = 'weight'
and t.value = 'red'
and t1.value = '2'
and t2.value = '3'
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06574d/4)

Answer (score 0):

If there's a lot of properties (only a few of which may be of interest), you may be better off with the [Star schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema) that was specifically invented for this case.

Less than 10 properties you described are hardly a justification for such complication though. You'll be just fine with the initial table in accordance with the KISS principle.

Comment: The problem is that the number of properties is slowly going to grow. At the initial state there are going to be about 200 properties and about 10000 IDs. What design would you use?

Comment: 200 is much enough for the star schema, I guess. It has variations for different use cases so you'd better read up on this topic.